# Is there a (pseudo)-standard for blog-feeds in JSON?

Tags: xml, json, feed

I'd really love to fully avoid using xml, but in the case of offering a feed for my blog, I'm stuck at the choice between RSS or ATOM, both xml. I read about making a standard for feeds in JSON years ago I think, but didn't see anything of that till today.
Is there something in the making? [Blogspot](http://beautifulbeta.wikidot.com/json-feeds) seems to offer a feed in JSON, but are there even feed-clients which can read the structure? Or will I need to depend on XML for the next few years?

Comment: What advantages of an alternative format are you looking for? Is it just a political/philosophical rejection of anything related to XML?

Comment: In my opinion, XML is just bloated. I in fact do not see any reason why to keep using it, so I switched to JSON in every possible case, especially APIs. And now I wonder what could be the deal with providing feeds.

Answer (score 1):

I think there  is not a real widely accepted one. There is an adaption of [*Atom* to *JSON*](http://yojava.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/atom-on-json/) and there is Google's older [*gdata*](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json). When accessing for example Blogger via REST API it uses a specific JSON format for posts. Wordpress has a [feed-json](https://wordpress.org/plugins/feed-json/) plugin, which features its own format - it does not look well described.

Comment: Thanks for the links; the simple mapping of known xml-tags of rss.js is a thought I already had in mind. I would hope that this would become some kind of convention one day...